# No wireless and wired on ubuntu 12.04 in Acer Aspire E1-570

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, acer, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. After running an update and restarting, on the top right it says **No Network Devices Available**. Linux can't find the network card. It was working fine earlier..

The command

```
dmesg | grep eth

[    0.793336] i2c-core: driver [aat2870] using legacy suspend method
[    0.793338] i2c-core: driver [aat2870] using legacy suspend method
```

It does not list any eth0/eth1/eth2 etc.

However,

```
lspci
```

outputs

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
```

The command

```
lshw -C network
```

outputs:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 01
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:c0410000-c041ffff memory:c0420000-c042ffff memory:c0430000-c043ffff
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wirelesss Network Adapter
    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
    version: 01
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:c0500000-c057ffff memory:afc00000-afc0ffff
```

Is there a problem with the drivers or something else?

Any help would be really appreciated.

---

**(Update)**

My friend tried cmake something again. And my wired connection is now working.

```
lshw -C network
```

now gives

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 01
   serial: 20:1a:06:ae:75:7c
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.133d duplex=full firmware=sb ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:16 memory:c0410000-c041ffff memory:c0420000-c042ffff memory:c0430000-c04307ff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0500000-c057ffff memory:afc00000-afc0ffff
```

And the dmesg output has also changed.

```
dmesg | grep eth

[    0.792213] i2c-core: driver [aat2870] using legacy suspend method
[    0.792215] i2c-core: driver [aat2870] using legacy resume method
[   12.067519] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM57786) rev 57766001] (PCI Express) MAC address 20:1a:06:ae:75:7c
[   12.067524] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: eth0: attached PHY is 57765 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   12.067528] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[   12.067531] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   13.730983] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   13.731750] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   16.108517] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[   16.108522] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: eth0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   16.108525] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: eth0: EEE is disabled
[   16.108658] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   26.640551] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

However, the wireless is still not working.
Hope the help would come more now!

Answer (score 1):

Your ethernet device works with the driver *tg3*; its device ID isn't included until later kernel versions than that included in Ubuntu 12.04. The same is true for your wireless device which, in later Ubuntu versions, is claimed by *ath9k*.

It will be extremely difficult to download and install a driver for the ethernet without wireless and vice-versa. I suggest you download the live DVD or USB for Ubuntu 13.10. I am quite confident that both devices will work as expected. If so, install 13.10.